# Умирают "screen'ы" в sudo

Tags: linux, bash

**Небольшое введение:**

Пишу собственного Бота на платформе VK. Не так давно сменил хостинг. Раньше я использовал для постоянной работы tmux и всё было прекрасно. Но сейчас на хостинге в моём распоряжении только 'screen', у которого постоянно почему-то умирают сессии.

**Суть проблемы:**

Мне нужно запускать бота, чтобы он работал 24/7. Запускаю отдельную сессию в screen: screen -S Bot. После же указываю сам запуск Бота: /opt/python/python-3.9.0/bin/python main.py. Однако через определённое время, Бот перестаёт работать, а при попытке посмотреть сессии screen вижу такое сообщение:

```
-bash-4.2$ screen -list
There is a screen on:
        24796.Bot       (Dead ???)
Remove dead screens with 'screen -wripe'.
1 Socet in var/run/screen/S-user... .
```

Много статей было прочитано, но ничего мне не помогло. На данный момент я пробую запускать Бота через 'DAEMON': screen -m -d -S Bot /opt/python/python-3.9.0/bin/python main.py.

Очень интересно почему умирают screen'ы. И хотелось бы узнать как исправить данную проблему и запускать Ботов на 24/7.

Всем спасибо за ответы.

---

**P.S:** Мне уже дали понять, что проблемы связаны с хостингом. Но что если переписать Longpoll Бота в CallBack Бота ? По идее постоянная работа скрипта как при Longpoll не потребуется, ведь достаточно иметь сайт на который будет приходить post запрос с ивентом. Получится ли тогда обеспечить бесперебойную работу бота ?

Ещё раз всем спасибо за ответы.

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, учту в следующих вопросах.

Comment: Потому что используемый вами хостинг запрещает запускать долгие процессы и через время убивает их, например?

Comment: Они умирают не только через длительный промежуток времени. Несколько раз такая проблема возникала и они умирали все через разный промежуток времени - 1 час, 5 часов, 20+ часов.

Comment: А ещё при чём тут sudo? В показанных вами сообщениях я не вижу никаких намёков на какое-либо использование sudo

Comment: Спасибо за изменения. Я новичок в этом плане и не особо разбираюсь что есть sudo, а что нет.

Comment: Ну а вообще для работы 24/7 следует использовать какой-нибудь нормальный менеджер служб (например systemd или supervisor), а не костылять через screen или tmux

Comment: "systemd или supervisor" для этих утилит требуется установка ? Как я понял в моём хостинге нельзя ничего стороннего установить.

Comment: Это намекает на то, что используемый вами хостинг скорее всего в принципе не предназначен для запуска ботов подобного рода. Для таких штук обычно берут VPS/VDS, получают полный контроль над системой и радуются жизни

Comment: Если в умирании не наблюдается закономерности, то можно предположить, что такой закономерностью может быть оперативка: как только бот сжирает слишком много памяти - хостинг решает убить все ваши процессы вместе со screen'ами. Если моё предположение окажется верным, то это ещё раз намекает на то, что хостинг в принципе не предназначен для подобных штук

Comment: Я хотел проверить информацию насчёт поедания ОЗУ, но не смог найти ни файлов с ошибками 'out of memory', ни информации сколько ОЗУ выделено на моём хостинге.

Comment: Вам уже намекнули. Давайте я артикулирую пояснее: меняйте ваш "хостинг" на нормальный, возможно, виртуальный, linux-сервер. Бессмысленно бороться с глюками, на которые вы никак не можете повлиять. Надо менять "железо".

Comment: `tmux` и `screen` являются мультиплексерами консольных сессий. Они не предназначены для запуска долгоживущих серверных процессов.

Comment: Всем спасибо за комментарии ! Мною было принято решение переписать Бота используя CallBack VK API. Учту все ваши замечания. Всем удачи!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самое **оптимальное решение** при желании остаться на действующем хостинге - переписать Бота, используя **CallBack VK API**. Благодаря этому повысится эффективность Бота, а также будет меньше проблем с 'tmux' и 'screen'.